# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java

So I'm currently just messing around with classes and objects to fully understand how it works, and tried to create a tiny search engine that would give information based on user input. The user basically has to enter the name of an animal (so far only 2 animals added).

I tried creating an if statement, so that if the input == animal (for instance a dolphin) it would spit out information on the dolphin. It won't recognize the "animal" in dolphin.animal, and I cannot seem to understand the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!
Here's my code:

```
package Zoo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Animals {

    //instance fields
    String Name;
    String Animal;
    String Color;
    int AgeYear;
    String FavoriteFood;


    //constructor method
    public Animals(String name, String animal, String color, int ageYear, String favoriteFood) {
        Name = name;
        Animal = animal;
        Color = color;
        AgeYear = ageYear;
        FavoriteFood = favoriteFood;
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animals dolphin = new Animals("Gretha", "dolphin", "gray", 2, "salmon");
        Animals orangutan = new Animals("Peter", "orangutan", "black", 15, "bananas");


        System.out.println("Please enter the name of an animal to view information regarding said animal.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.nextLine();

        if(input == dolphin.animal)  {
            System.out.println(dolphin.Animal + dolphin.Name + dolphin.AgeYear + dolphin.Color + dolphin.FavoriteFood);

        }


    }
}
```

EDIT: yes I'm aware that the outprint is unfinished, but that I can fix afterwards of course

Comment: The field you have defined is called `dolphin.Animal`, not `dolphin.animal`.

Comment: `input` is a `Scanner` not a string

Comment: You read nextLine but don't assign it to a variable.

Comment: Please don't edit things like 'solved' into your question. I have rolled back that edit. If you managed to solve your problem, either accept the answer that helped you solve the problem, or post an answer with your solution and accept it after the timeout.

Comment: I will remember than next time, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*javadoc* is your friend. Method [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) in class `Scanner` returns a `String`. You need to save that value in a variable, for example using this code:

```java
String theName = input.nextLine();
```

Then you need to use method `equals()` to see if `theName` equals "dolphin", i.e.

```java
if (theName.equals(dolphin.Animal)) {
   // print the details
}
```

By the way, if you adhere to the [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) you make it easier for others to read and understand your code.

Comment: Thank you! This made it all work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input == dolphin.animal)
```

should be

```
if (input == dolphin.Animal)
```

also you have to assign the result of input.nextLine() to a variable and then compare that variable with dolphin.Animal